# wireless problem in android

Tags: android, connection

I have to check wireless network enabled or disabled in android. How to do that?

I have to check this one.(setting->location & security->use wireless networks) not in the(Settings -> Wireless & network settings -> wifi).  I tried for second one.

In the coding even though I on the air plane mode it is shown Internet Connection Present. So I have to check wireless in setting->location & security->use wireless networks.

my code:

```
 private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // test for connection
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Internet Connection Present");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "Internet Connection Not Present");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

please assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check (setting->location & security->use wireless networks) then you have to check this condition

```
private boolean connectionAvailable() {
    boolean connected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        //we are connected to a network
        connected = true;
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean connectionAvailable() {
    boolean connected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        //we are connected to a network
        connected = true;
    }
    return connected;
}
```